# Can I use inline-css to make expandable content?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a landing page in an asp.net storefront and am wanting to add expandable content. I've been told I should be using inline styles for this - not an internal style sheet, and because there is psuedo styles in the css I can't make my content expand when I inline it.

Are there any options as to how to create expandable content with an inline style?

```css
/* Accordian Items */
.collapse {
 text-align:left;
}

.collapse > * + *{
  display:none;
  
 }
.collapse > *{
  cursor:pointer;
  }
  
.collapse:focus{
  outline:none;
}
.collapse:focus > * + *{
  display:block; 
}

.accordian-cta {
 width:20%;
 float: right;
 vertical-align:middle;
 text-align:right;
}

.accordian-title {
 width:100%;
 max-width:1000px;
 
 text-indent:10px;
 margin-bottom:10px;
 color:rgb(71,70,70);
 font-size:1.17em;
 font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:5px;
```

```html
<div class="collapse" tabindex="3">
     <div class="accordian-title">Click to expand<div class="accordian-cta">+&nbsp;</div> </div>
     <div class="accordian-text">
     [EXPANDED CONTENT HERE]

     
     </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You have to try using jquery/javascript to use inline style for collapse/expand

Comment: Is that your project use jQuery ? it will be easier with some javascript. I think it's not possible with just inline css :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't with inline css, but IMHO there is no point constraining your code this way. Here is an other example in pure css, using an input of type checkbox:

```css
#expand {
  display: none;
}
#toggle:checked ~ #expand {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox" checked>
<label for="toggle">Hide/Show</label>
<p id="expand">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</p>
```

It differs from your code by not toggling the content when losing the focus, which is more "stable" for a user.

You can add more css to make a transition on the height instead of a brute "display/no-display", or style the checkbox in a more fashion way, like [here](https://codepen.io/peternguyen/pen/hICga).

More info on css selectors [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Thanks very much for this. That's very useful and I think I might use something like this thank you!

Comment: After more lengthy chats with my developers it appears that I can use an internal stylesheet but there is a risk that the styles will be stripped so they don't recommend it. I will give this one a go and see how it goes